# The return value of model.evaluate_generator

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I don't understand: since that the model is evaluated on a group of images, not a single image, so I think the score should return the average value of loss or metrics over the group of images.
score = model.evaluate_generator(evaluateGene,test_images, verbose=1)

This is a neural network model based on Keras, to evaluate the performance of the model, we need to calculate the average loss and metrics and their standard deviation.

```py
    score = model.evaluate_generator(evaluateGene,test_images, verbose=1)
    print('%.3f' %score[0], '%.3f' %score[1],'%.3f' %score[2])
```

Since I want to calculate the mean loss, metrics and standard deviation. But this function seems can't do that. Are there some good solutions to return a mean value and std? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What makes you think evaluate_generator does not return mean loss and metrics already? It doesn't compute standard deviation for sure.

Comment: Sorry, I mean this function can only return the mean loss, metrics, but no std. So I was wondering if there is a method to calculate the std?